# changing process.env variables with jest in tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test a function, which has multiple `if` statements with variables from `process.env`.

I was trying to write a test in `jest` like this:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  delete process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
  delete process.env.REACT_APP_URL;
});

it('no URL', () => { 
  process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'api_key';
 
  try {
    buildUrl(mockMethod, null);
  } catch (err) {
    expect(err.message).toBe('REACT_APP_API_KEY is not specified!');
  }
});

it('no method', () => { 
  process.env.REACT_APP_URL = 'mock_url';
  process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'api_key';

  try {
    buildUrl(mockMethod, null);
  } catch (err) {
    expect(err.message).toBe('REACT_APP_API_KEY is not specified!');
  }
});
```

But the problem is that the variables don't get deleted after every test. They get cached somehow and not set anymore.

Maybe someone has encountered this problem and has some tips on how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, the culprit was that I was deconstructing `process.env` values in the upper part of the file - not in the function as itself + I was renaming them.

```js
const buildUrl = (method: string, page: number = 1): string => {
  const { API_KEY, URL } = process.env;
  //...
  
  // vs
  
const {
  API_KEY: MY_API_KEY,
  URL: MY_URL
} = process.env;

const buildUrl = (method: string, page: number = 1): string => {
  const MY_API_KEY = ...
```